# Is there anyway to register only for some memebrs of a class when using MPI_Type_create_struct?

Tags: types, mpi

I have a very simple struct as :

```
struct foo {
    int x; 
    int y; 
    foo(int _x , int _y ): x(_x),y(_y){}; 
    foo(int _x): x(_x){}; 
    void print(){
        std::cout<<"x: "<<x<<" y: "<<y<<std::endl;
    }

};
```

As you can see, I have two constructors. In portion of the program that I need to implement MPI on that, I only need to use the second constructor and I only need to know the value of x. I have defined a function to register my type for MPI:

```
 MPI_Datatype register_mpi_type(foo const&){
    constexpr std::size_t lengths=1; 
    int block_length[lengths]= {1};
    MPI_Aint displacements [lengths]; 
    MPI_Aint base_address; 
    displacements[0]=offsetof(foo,x); 
    MPI_Datatype types[lengths] = { MPI_INT32_T};
    
    MPI_Datatype type; 
    MPI_Type_create_struct(lengths,block_length, displacements, types, &type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&type);
    return type; 
}
```

The thing is, if I run the following code, I won't get the value of x for the second element of `std::vector<foo>`, sugeesting that there is something wrong with memory alignment.

```
MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); 
emInt rank, size; 
emInt SENDER=0; 
emInt RECEIVER=1; 
emInt tag=0; 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank); 

foo dummy(1); 
MPI_Datatype fooType = register_mpi_type(dummy); 
if(rank==SENDER){
        foo obj1 (10); 
        foo obj2(100); 
        std::vector<foo> dummy; 
        dummy.push_back(obj1); 
        dummy.push_back(obj2); 

        for(auto i=0; i<2; i++){
            dummy[i].print(); 
        }
        MPI_Send(dummy.data(),2,fooType,RECEIVER,
        tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    }if(rank==RECEIVER){
        std::vector<foo> dummy(2,foo(1)); 
        MPI_Recv(dummy.data(),2,fooType,SENDER,tag,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        for(auto i=0; i<2; i++){
            dummy[i].print(); 
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
```

The dummy prints:

```
x: 10 y: 32766
x: 100 y: 32766
x: 10 y: 32766
x: 1 y: 32766
```

However, if I change my mpi type function to register for `y` as well, I get what I expect. The value of x for the second element will be correct.
I know in this example, I might not even need to register since it only has one member of interest. But, I'm trying to mimic the bahvior of larger application. In real project, I have a class with 20 members that I only need to communicate objects that are constructed with only 5 members. Do I need to include all 20 members in my MPI register type? or Will be any workaround? I know if I'm only interested in passing one object, it will be fine, but when I have `std::vector<object>`, I can't get the correct value for elements after the first one.